# Predicting pH of an acidic salt of an weak acid and weak base

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution

Suppose we want to calculate pH of an $\ce{NH4HCO3}$ solution of known concentration.
Now, $\ce{NH4+}$ will be hydrolised to give $\ce{H+}$ ions.
Some $\ce{HCO3-}$ ions will be converted to (i) $\ce{H2CO3}$ and $\ce{OH-}$
and some will give (ii) $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{CO3^2-}$

\begin{align}
\ce{HCO3- + H2O &<=> H2CO3 + OH− }& 1/K_\mathrm{a1}\\
\ce{HCO3- + H2O &<=> CO3^2- + H3O+ }& K_\mathrm{a2}\\
\ce{NH4+ + H2O &<=> NH3 (aq) + H3O+ }& 1/K_\mathrm{b}\\
\end{align}

1. I am not sure how to take account of both $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in the calculation of pH.
2. Will the third equilibium costant be $1/K_\mathrm{b}$?

Comment: Can you use the formula given in my answer and check if if it gives you the correct answer?

Comment: 3rd equilibrium is written terribly - it's simply NH4+ +H2o = NH3 +H3o+ (proton exchange)

Comment: @Mithoron: That's the reaction given in my textbook. User intends hydrolysis of cation. BTW, did the formula work?

Comment: @AdityaDev You should get new textbook ;) "NH4OH" is only in old ones - there's no such molecule, there's NH3(aq) written instead now

Comment: My supervisor spent about five minutes grinning and laughing about a practical joke a TA did in an undergrad lab course to a fellow student, sending her away to get ‘solid $\ce{NH4OH}$’ while telling us the story in the post-serious drinking session during a symposium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reactions which take place are

1)Ionization of $\ce{HA-}$: $\ce{HA- -> H+ +A^2-}$

2)Hydrolysis of $\ce{HA-}$: $\ce{HA- + H+ -> H2A}$

3)Hydrolysis of cation: $\ce{B+ + H2O -> BOH + H+}$

for reaction $1$, $$k_{a2}=\frac{[H^+][A^{2-}]}{[HA^-]}$$

for reaction $2$, $$k_{a1}=\frac{[HA^-][H^+]}{[H_2A]}$$

for reaction $3$, $$k_h=\frac{k_w}{k_b}=\frac{[BOH][H^+]}{[B^+]}$$

At any moment, $$\ce{[H^+]=[BOH] +[A^{2-}]-[H2A]}$$
$$[H^+]=\frac{[NH^{4+}].k_w}{[H^+]k_b}+\frac{k_{a2}.[HCO_3^-]}{[H^+]}-\frac{[HCO_3^-][H^+]}{k_{a1}}$$
Rearranging the terms to get $\ce{[H+]}$,
$$[H^+]=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{[NH_4^+].k_w}{k_b}+k_{a2}[HCO_3^-]}{1+\frac{[HCO_3^-]}{k_{a1}}}}$$
$$[H^+]=\sqrt{\frac{k_{a1}\cdot \big(\frac{[NH_4^+].k_w}{k_b}+k_{a2}[HCO_3^-]\big)}{k_{a1}+[HCO_3^-]}}$$

Now we will have to make 2 assumptions. First lets assume that $k_{a1}<<[HCO_3^-]$ so that $k_{a1}+[HCO_3^-]=[HCO_3^-]$

$$[H^+]=\sqrt{\frac{k_{a1}\cdot \big(\frac{[NH_4^+].k_w}{k_b}+k_{a2}[HCO_3^-]\big)}{[HCO_3^-]}}$$

If you assume that neither hydrolysis nor the dissociation goes too far, you can assume the concentration of bicarbonate ion to be equal to the initial concentration (say C). Since Ammonium bicarbonate dissociates to give two products in 1:1 ratio, concentration of ammonium produced is equal to the concentration of bicarbonate ion produced.

> I saw this formula for calculation pH of such salts in my textbook but
>   no derivation was given:
>   $$[H^+]=\sqrt{k_{a1}\cdot\big(\frac{k_w}{k_b}+k_{a2}\big)}$$ The above formula can
>   be obtained if you consider the last assumption. (Clarification
>   needed)

Comment: I don't understand why $\ce {[H+]=[B+]  + [A2−] − [H2A]}$ It should be $\ce [BOH]  + [A2−] − }$ [how to take acount of this? here OH- was produced]

Comment: I have edited that part. It's not B+. It's BOH. Reason is, H+ is produced by B+ and equal amount of H+ and BOH are formed. So [H+] from B+ is same as the amount of BOH formed.

Comment: And, how do you take account of the last part? (why $\ce {−[H2A]}$) I mean, how to substitute the [OH-]?

Comment: Amount of H+ used up and amount of H2A formed are same.

Comment: If you have any numerical type question, see if the formula works.

Comment: I don't have the answer. Our teacher gave this to think. But I could not figure out what to do with the OH- in the reaction 2. Thanks. Will let you know when I have the answer.